# Difference between Object Identifier(OID) and Primary Key in terms of Object Oriented Design?

Tags: database, oop, object, jdbc, object-oriented-analysis

Well I know what OID is and means but is it same as Primary Key?In that case, how is it same and what are the differences between the two (if any)?

Comment: What database are you using, because OID is not generic database term; it is for example used in PostgreSQL, but that is really an implementation detail of PostgreSQL. The term itself is not related to JDBC at all. Also, your question is rather unclear.

Comment: what i meant was , I wanted to know if the concept of OID and primary key is same or not...in a general sense..what is similar between the two?I am not taking into consideration which database I am dealing with, I am speaking in a general approach..I know OID is uniquely given to every object and it cannot be retrieved or changed..neither does it make any sense in terms of its value, and I know we assign a primary key in a database but, is there any similarity between the two in terms of concept,property or definition??

Comment: As an OID isn't a general concept, but an implementation detail of one or more databases, this isn't really answerable without you specifying which database you are talking about.

Answer (score 2):

Not all databases have Object Identifiers (OIDs). If you use PostgreSQL, it is an internal identifier used by PostgreSQL to identify system tables. You do not add OIDs to your user-created tables. The primary key is defined when you create your tables. But of course, you still can use OIDs (if so desired) by specifying *WITH OIDS* when you create your table. Attached is a link to the PostgreSQL documentation for you to review. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/datatype-oid.html